# How do I extend the 32-bit limitation in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, logic, bit

We've been using bit operations to offer users the ability to customize the sections of a report. Each section has a bit value, and the sum of all the sections that the user chooses to include is the user's preference. We can then use bit operations to determine which sections to display on the user's report.

However, ColdFusion bit operations are limited to 32-bit numbers, and the number of sections on our report may soon exceed this limitation. We'd like to develop a method to perform bit operations with 64-bit numbers and higher. Is there any built-in way to accomplish this in CF? If not, how can we go about accomplishing this manually? (i.e. breaking the 64 bit number into 2 separate 32 bit numbers, performing the bit operations, and joining it back together)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perhaps use a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead?

Comment: So I would do all the bitwise operations in Java rather than CF?

Comment: Yes, you must use the [java bitwise methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#and%28java.math.BigInteger%29) because the CF versions of those functions will throw overflow errors with larger integers.

Comment: But - to clarify - you don't need to do it "in Java" (ie: make a Java class to do it), you can do it from CFML, just calling your BigInteger object's methods.